# Use cmder as default shell in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmder

Every other solution I can find to this question says to put the settings below inside my.vscode/settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
 "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
     "/K",
     "C:\\softwares\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
],
```

This  worked until recently, when I removed my settings file from a git repo. Now when I hover over the code above, I get this text in a popup

> The path of the shell that the terminal uses on Windows (default:
> C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe). Read more
> about configuring the shell. This is deprecated, use
> `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#` instead(2)

This is a bit confusing to me, I'm not sure what I have to change to what. I tried changing the first setting to

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```

But this has had no effect. Cmder is not being used as the default shell.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode changed how integrated terminal profiles are handled in [April 2021](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_terminal). Based on the args you provided in your question, adding this to your `settings.json` should work:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [
                "/K",
                "C:\\softwares\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
            ], 
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```

Comment: I don't understand why you both are launching via an init.bat file inside of cmd??? When you download cmder for Windows 10, it comes as an executable (i.e. the shell program) wrapped in zip file. Why  would you open a shell just to run a command that runs another shell??? Feels a bit counterintuitive to me...

Comment: I'm basically porting the same functionality that OP wanted to the new settings configuration. These settings are the same as what previously worked for OP

Answer (score 1):

[cmder](https://cmder.net/) comes as an executable program. You do not need to use a batch script to open it. Just firing the exe starts the program.

(from the official download page:)

1. Unzip
2. (optional) Place your own executable files into the bin folder to be injected into
   your PATH.
3. Run Cmder (Cmder.exe)

Therefore, you just need to add a single line to settings.json:

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\full\\path\\to\\unzipped\\cmder.exe"`

This shouldn't need to take in any flags or commands, args, unless you are wanting to change it's default functionalities (such as changing the default folder that the cursor points to on launch). For default cmder, just run the exe...

Comment: This will result in the warning: "This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`. This will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that will change in the future."

Answer (score -1):

try add follow config in settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```

> A path that when set will override terminal.integrated.shell.windows and ignore shellArgs values for automation-related terminal usage like tasks and debug.

Comment: This just launches the Windows terminal. OP is trying to launch a 3rd party downloaded shell.

Comment: Just change the config value to the 3rd party downloaded shell path.